# Neo4j - match nodes with multiple connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

In my db there are controllers and devices. Between them there are two connections, one direct logical connection, and one phisical connection through a cable node.

A) The logical connection is quite straightforward, the controller and the device is simpli connected through a connection called "logicalConn".

B) The phisical connection is trickier. The controller is a parent of CTRL_ENDP (endpoint) node, and the device is a parent of DEV_ENDP node. Those endpoints are than connected with a CABLE node. the CABLE node has two types of connections a source and a target.

Here is an example:

```
      ___________________[:controls]__________________
     /                                                \
    /                                                  \
   /                                                    \
CONTROLLER                                             DEVICE
   \                                                    /
  [:parentOf]                                        [:parentOf]
     \                                                / 
   CTRL_ENDP --- [:src] --- CABLE --- [:tar] --- DEV_ENDP
```

What I need to do?
So in a perfect scenario every controller is connectod to a certain device through both phisical and logical connections. But I need to determine if that is really the case! 
So I need two queries:

1) First query should return with a controller and a device if they are not connected logically, only phisically.

2) Second query should return the same, only this time in reverse, so when they are not connected phisically, only logically.

If the above two can be zipped into one query its good also, but for a simpler solution maybe we should have two queries as I described above.

I appreciate if someone could help me with that!

EDIT:

Additional info:

- This query will be used for validation for the whole DB to find those ctrl-dev pairs that are not connected properly. Therefore the solution must query the whole graph, not just the certain controller-device pair.
- Between a controller (A) and a targed device (B) there can be immediary devices physically. Like this: A - cable - C - cable - D - cable - B, where C and D are also devices, and it should also return true as physical connection between A and B.

Comment: Are there any patterns (in relationships and/or nodes) between a connected Controller and Device node that will always hold true? Specifically I'm looking for info which would let us constrain matched paths based upon the types of nodes in the path, or the types of relationships. Or is it enough just to find any connecting path that doesn't include :logicalConn to count as a physical connection?

Comment: I think just to find a way for the other node is not a good option, because for example the cable node has a parent called 'cables', and his parent is 'building'. So when we find new routes it might go up to cables, building, and will find a connection to the device that way, but that would be totally wrong.

And yes, there is a pattern. between a device and a controller always this pattern that I described in the original post. The difiiculty is that the pattern of the lower path can happen multiple times in a row.

Comment: In that case are there relationships or labels that we can use to blacklist a path to prevent matching down down paths you want to avoid?

Comment: the controller and the device has the same parent: building. And the cable has a parent called cables, and its parent is also building. So we should blacklist these, not to go up there and find a false route.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the specified patterns to determine if such a path exists between the two nodes, interpret those as booleans, and output those in the return:

I'll assume you're looking up the :DEVICE and :CONTROLLER nodes by something like an id parameter, let's use $devId and $conId as the input parameters:

```
MATCH (c:CONTROLLER {id:$conId}), (d:DEVICE {id:$devId})
WITH exists((c)-[:logicalConn]-(d)) as logicallyConnected,
 exists((c)-[:parentOf]-()-[:src]-()-[:tar]-()-[:parentOf]-(d)) as physicallyConnected
RETURN logicallyConnected, physicallyConnected
```

For the given patterns, all we're interested in is the structure, in this case the relationship types. If there can be different labeled nodes connected by those relationship types that you don't want to traverse, then you may want to add the labels to the node placeholders in the path, otherwise the relationship types should be enough.

Comment: I forgot to tell some additional info. Please look at the stuff I wrote after EDIT in the original post.